# Read XML node.text as HTML in nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I'm parsing a Reddit RSS feed with Nokogiri for a certain subreddit.

I'm trying to capture the external URL of the post if it goes to a certain domain.

Unfortunately, even if the post created by the user links to an external website, all of the RSS titles go to that reddit post (comment area) regardless. There is one attribute called `description` however, generated by the Reddit RSS feed, which DOES include an HTML string that includes two links:

[link][2 comments]

It is always the second to last anchor in the description.text

With Nokogiri, I can get down to the part where I pull the entire description into a string, and then I instantiate a new `Nokogiri::HTML` object with this string.

I'm wondering two things:

1. Is there a way to convert a string to `Nokogiri::HTML` so I dont need to create a new object?
2. How do I save the `href` value for the second to last link which appears in the description?

Code:

```
def scrape
  @document = Nokogiri::XML(open(self.url))
  @document.xpath("//item").each do |item|
    description_html = item.xpath('description').text
    url = Nokogiri::HTML(description_html)... #?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out

```
def scrape
  document = Nokogiri::XML(open(self.url))
  document.xpath('//item').each do |item|
    description_html = item.xpath('description').text
    url = Nokogiri::HTML(description_html).xpath('//a')[-2]['href']
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, often its necessary to parse chunks of content multiple times just to unravel all the encoding that might have occurred during the feed's construction.